# [SeleniumRC]Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined in Chrome

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc

Please help me to fix this issue (Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined in Chrome). I'm running selenium using .NET framework and I don't see any overload method in selenium.start to pass "--disable-web-security".

My selenium server is selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pritam

Answer (score 0):

`-disable-web-security` is a browser configuration and not a selenium server option. In Java, you can declare it as follows -

```
BrowserConfigurationOptions bco = new BrowserConfigurationOptions();
bco.setCommandLineFlags("-disable-web-security");
```

Do this prior to initializing the Selenium server.